# .htaccess remove extension and get query param

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess is this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

I want to add, also to remove the PHP extension to the page, another things. Redirect the query. Example i have this page:

```
https://mywebsite.it/room?id=1
```

Externally i want to show in this way:

```
https://mywebsite.it/room/1
```

But internally need to redirect always to room?id=1, so i can use $_GET

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you hitting link `https://mywebsite.it/room?id=1` in browser?

Comment: Actually, yes. But i want to hit "mywebsite.it/room/1" and internally redirect to "mywebsite.it/room?id=1" without show to the user

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```bash
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

## external redirect from /room?id=123 to /room/123 URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\(room)(?:\.php)?\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]

## To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

## internal rewrite to from /room/111 to room.php?id=1.php
RewriteRule ^(room)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

## To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.